# types in template specialization (unique_ptr for array types)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

unique_ptr has an option to take array types - to have correct deleter (with array delete[]) later:

`std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> up(new std::string[10]); // OK`

the definition of unique_ptr class itself include specialization for this type (note T[] braces near the definition itself):

```
template<typename T, typename D>
class unique_ptr<T[], D> { ... }
```

but isn't it the string[] or int[] itself a type
so it should be templated to the T type according to the definition not T[]?
in other words HOW do the template engine differs between T and T[] (if we just substitute T for string[] - the T[] specialization should give us string[][] type or it shouldn't? 
if we just typedef int[] for array_to_int type wouldnt the T[] substitution be array_to_int[] type (ie int[][] type)?

in other words, we explicitly pass std::string[] TYPE to template in here
`std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>`
and it should be substituted to T itself , right? not T[] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a partial specialization of the `std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>` class template that is declared as follows:

```
template<class _Ty, class _Dx>
class unique_ptr<_Ty[], _Dx> ... // this is the partial specialization
```

Through template deduction rules, when the template parameter `_Ty` is `T[]`, the partial specialization is chosen. This partial specialization provides the functionalities unique to `std::unique_ptr<_Ty[], _Dx>` such as `operator[]` (which isn't defined for non-array template arguments).

**Selection process for template specializations**

To begin with, the primary template is always the one that is looked up. The arguments that you instantiate a template class or template function are then checked with any available specializations of that template class or template function. Following this, the most specialized one (best match) is selected. In your case, `std::string[]` matches the `T[]` specialization more than it matches `T` from the primary template.

Comment: but why the supplied type (say int[]) itself is not substituted for T? i.e. why it is substitutes for T + []

Comment: @barney It might help to think of partial specializations as pattern matching. You don't supply arguments to the partial specialization; rather, it will be used if the supplied arguments to the primary template match the pattern.

Comment: @T.C. so when I write partial specialization and extend type T with [] or * or whatever - it rather reviews it as pattern match / element of my type itself? and thus T[] is not addition of [] to T right? (What confuses me that in other part of the language I can actually ADD something to my type:  
`template <typename T> using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T,void(*)(T*)>;` would replace my original `UniquePtr<int>` to `std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)>` effectively adding something to the Type

Comment: T is not substituted by T + []. It's like you have a square hole and a round hole of the same diameter. You can fit round pegs into square holes, but the best match for round pegs is the round hole. So while yes, std::string[] (round peg) does match T (square hole), it matches T[] (round hole) even better. Therefore, the partial template specialization for T[] is chosen when the template argument is an array. Both options are available from the start, and the best one is picked.